# xcodebuild, missing iOS simulator sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm automating the building process for an iOS project. Everything was fine... but now I have to support iOS 4, what I have installed is the iOS simulator 4.3 (Xcode : Preferences > Downloads > Components).

Inside xcode I have these options:

- iOS device
- iPad simulator 5.0
- iPad simulator 5.1
- iPhone simulator 5.0
- iPhone simulator 5.1

**There is no** 4.3

From command line

```
$ xcodebuild -showsdks
Mac OS X SDKs:
    Mac OS X 10.6                   -sdk macosx10.6
    Mac OS X 10.7                   -sdk macosx10.7

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 5.0                         -sdk iphoneos5.0

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 5.0             -sdk iphonesimulator5.0
```

**There is no** 4.3

Questions:

1. Where is the 4.3 simulator installed?
2. What sdk value should a pass to xcodebuild for the 4.3 simulator?

Thanks guys.

Comment: What you actually need is the iOS4.3 SDK (for the simulator platform) and not the simulator itself, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simulator SDK's are located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

You can use the following `xcodebuild` (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`) command:

```
xcodebuild -target $target -sdk $sdk -configuration $configuration
```

where `$target` is the target name specified in the project, `$sdk` could be taken from the output of the command you used to see the available SDK's (`iphoneos5.0`, `iphonesimulator5.0`) and `$configuration` could be `AdHoc`, `AppStore` or whatever else you have setup in the project.

For the missing SDK issue you could check the item status at `Xcode : Preferences > Downloads > Components` to be `Installed` and check the folder `iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk` exists at the SDK's location. If it does but still not displayed as installed, you could consider removing and reinstalling it or reinstall the Xcode completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have iOS Lion.
Follow the following steps

Go to Applications
(Right click on Xcode Icon)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/ Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

There you will find the iOS Simulator App.