# Simulator SDKs missing in xcode build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have found many tutorials (such as [this one](http://immersedcode.org/2011/4/25/sdl-on-ios/)) that mention being able to set the base SDK for a project's build settings to use, say, the iPhone Simulator.  I am running the latest version of Xcode but the only SDKs that seem to be available are MacOS and iOS.  Even after downloading some of the older simulators from Preferences>Downloads, I don't see any additional SDKs available.

I don't know if I broke something, or if I'm not even supposed to be able to select any of the simulator SDKs as the base SDK.  I'm still too new to Xcode to really know.  From questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356880/xcodebuild-missing-ios-simulator-sdk), I'd assume that I should be seeing at least an "iOS Simulator" as an option.

I previously was trying to experiment with compiling via makefiles and so was installing various command line tools, so I'm not sure if something just messed up my environment.  I tried uninstalling xcode and developer tools entirely and reinstalling from the latest version on the app store, but it doesn't seem like it changed anything.  I can't even seem to get an existing project to build for the simulator, when a while back it used to be able to, so it doesn't even seem to matter which project I have open.

Did I break something, or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your build settings and xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something obvious. :)

The Base SDK has nothing to do with running on a device or the simulator. Leave the Base SDK as "Latest".

To run your app in the simulator, notice the dropdown menu in the toolbar just to the right of the Play and Stop icons. In the dropdown, choose the target to build and then the device or simulator you want to run with. Once chosen, go to the Product menu and choose Run (Cmd-R).

Comment: Aha!  Did earlier versions of xcode have that choice as part of the project settings?  Some of these out-of-date tutorials can really send me down the wrong holes, being so unfamiliar with xcode.  Setting the scheme to "simulator" is exactly what I needed to do, and now I'm getting all my projects and SDKs to compile with the right symbols.  Thanks!